# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version') in Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to build a project in Appcelerator Studio 5.0 and Titanium SDK 7.0.1. I am facing a build error.

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')

I have already updated the Google Play Services in my SDK. But still facing the error. Tried clean and build.Still no luck. Any solutions?

Comment: Please add the modules and their version that you are using. That error sounds like an old ti.map version

Comment: @miga : the modules used are : <module platform="android" version="2.3.10">ti.map</module><module platform="android" version="2.2.2">ti.imagefactory</module><module platform="android" version="3.4.1">ti.cloudpush</module><module platform="android" version="1.0.0">com.device.settings</module>

Answer (score 1):

Your modules are too old! The map module e.g. is from 2016 and doesn't support Ti SDK 7. Same for the ti.imagefactory.

If you have the newest version of the modules installed you can remove the `version` attribute so it will use the latest version. Maps and cloud should be included, for imagefactory download the latest version at:

- https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.imagefactory/releases
- https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map/releases